# Is there any version of Ubuntu that does not require PAE?

Tags: cpu, xubuntu, pae

For the first time I tried to install Xubuntu 12.04 on my computer using the Grub4dos way. However, it stuck and showed "This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU : PAE". I therefore checked my device and found that my CPU is Dothan, which is quite old and without PAE. So I wonder if I can solve the problem by choosing another kernel that does not require PAE. Thx 4 ur help.

Answer (score 2):

Try the non-pae mini cd. It will boot into netboot, and download the needed files

- [Link](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/installer-i386/current/images/netboot/non-pae/)

This is a simple iso file for the kernel and the drivers. You just boot this as you would a normal iso, but it has a text based installer. You nearly just press enter all the time. You have to give once the username and then password. At partitioning you just select the the guided one (without LVM) and on the package selection you select Xubuntu desktop.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I am not quite sure about how to use that stuff. And since I am sort of a noob, I would choose iso to install it. Could you please give me further explanation?

Comment: This is a simple iso file for the kernel and the drivers. You just boot this as you would a normal iso, but it has a text based installer. You nearly just press enter all the time. You have to give once the username and then password. At partitioning you just select the the guided one (without LVM) and on the package selection you select Xubuntu desktop.

Comment: Thanks a million mate, I would probably try right now LOL

Comment: But do I have to download all the stuff included in the Link?

Comment: no, just the mini.iso

Answer (score 0):

A few weeks ago I installed Ubuntu 12.04 Alpha 1 on a laptop which I'm pretty sure does not support PAE without any problems. I suspect this PAE requirement may be a mis-feature (bug) of the current Xubuntu installer.

Comment: ... no - no bug - the default 32bit kernel now in ubuntu/kubuntu etc is the PAE kernel

Comment: Oh really? So I can report the bug or something like that???

Comment: This is not a bug. The x86 line kernels will be built only with pae enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Xubuntu 12.04 was using the PAE kernel - the newer builds have reverted to the non PAE kenel now.

Comment: Are you saying that Quantal is using a non-PAE kernel??

Comment: No - that was in March and about 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

On my non-PAE [AMD Geode LX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geode_%28processor%29#Geode_LX) based [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/business/server/overview) system I installed [11.10](http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/) first and then made a distribution upgrade to [12.04](http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/).